# Browser problems in loading websites in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, browser, websites

I got a new Ubuntu 16.04 box on my company network, but the browsers (chrome, Firefox, ...) have problems opening many websites. For instance, Linkedin.com opens like this:
[image: Screenshot]

I thoutght it has problems opening images, bug Google images shows images with now problem. I have no problems on my Windows laptop connecting to the same company network.

**UPDATE:** I was trying to download an IDE, and realized while `http://www.eclipse.org/` opens, it doesn't open `https://www.eclipse.org/` (the download pages uses `HTTPS`). When I change the URL to HTTP, it works and I can download the resource. So I'm guessing some security problems might be blocking **HTTPS**.

What is the problem? How to resolve it?

Comment: This happens in your home network?

Comment: I had the same problem, using Tor Browser solved it.

Comment: It's a company network

Comment: @Coditoergosum the Tor browser can't be downloaded also! With wget, I get this: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden`

Comment: Then maybe they have some kind of filter (like squid), that prevents access to some sites.

Comment: I can not even see the screenshot I uploaded. The page doens't load!

Comment: It's common for private networks to filter content and deny access to sites, to control the bandwith.

Comment: Well, on my windows laptop on company network I have no issues. This only happens here.

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe you can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1157028/edit) your question to add this information.

Comment: Looks like a bandwidth problem, not a browser problem. The browser is not receiving all of the page GETs. Could be the network (proxy, filter), or the Ubuntu networking stack (unlikely - then you would receive nothing at all). If the box is mobile, try it on  a different network. If immobile, get your company IT folks involved.

Comment: @Ariana you can use your cellphone to download tor browser,

Comment: Open **Network** from **Tools|Web Developer** menu in Firefox. (The shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+E`). Then reload the page and try to find the components of the page that do not load properly: Sort by **Transferred** or **Size**. Find the lines with 0 value. Select one such line and go to **Timings** on the right.

Comment: Look at my edit: HTTPS has problems. The developer tools shows many errors in connection establishments: `net::ERR_FAILED`